# Is $F(x)=\frac{1}{\pi}\tan^{-1}(x),-\infty<x<\infty$ a distribution function?

Tags: probability-theory

Check whether  $F(x)=\frac{1}{\pi}\tan^{-1}(x),-\infty<x<\infty$ is a distribution function?

***What I attempted:-*** There are three conditions for a function $F(x)$ to be a distribution function. 
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
&(1)\mbox{It should be non-decreasing}\\
&(2)\mbox{It should be right continuous} \\
&(3)\mbox{$F(-\infty)=0$ and $F(\infty)=1$}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation} 
$(2)$ $\tan^{-1}x$ is continuous over the real line.

$(1)$ $F'(x)=\frac{1}{\pi}\frac{1}{1+x^2}>0 \quad \forall x\in R$

$(3)$ $F(\infty)=\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{1}{\pi}\tan^{-1}x=\frac{1}{\pi}\times \frac{\pi}{2}=\frac{1}{2}\not=1$. Am I correct?

Thus it couldn't be a distribution function.

Comment: Sure you were not asked about $F(x)=\frac12+\frac1\pi\tan^{-1}x$ instead?

Comment: Yes, the question was asked about that function only which I presented here. Of course, the function that you have revealed is a distribution function of the Cauchy Distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right, it fails the condition that $F(\infty)=1$, hence it can't be a CDF.

Also, $F$ takes negative values at negative $x$, for example, $F(-1)<0$.